# Angular 2+ : custom HTTP header in a Blob Response

Tags: angular, http, blob, response, custom-headers

I have to get a custom HTTP header sent by the nodejs backend in an Angular 2+ application.

To do so, I use the following code :

```
const custom-header = res.headers.get('custom-header');
```

It works well for default Requests and Responses, but when I specified a Blob type using :

```
let options = this._appService.getOptions();
options.responseType = ResponseContentType.Blob;

return this._http.get(this._appService.backEndUrl + '/information/getFile?filename=' + nameFile, options);
```

The custom header is not available in Angular (though visible in the browser network viewer).

How can I get a custom header in a Blob Response ?